# Common problems while moving classes between packages in a maven project

Tags: java, persistence

During a refactor, we moved some classes to another module and updated all the imports properly. But we faced some issues with JSONDeserializer which is saving  the complete class path. The old object was serialized with old class path and saved in the DB. Now with these new changes, during read, it could not find the class because the class path has changed.

Now I'm wondering if there are any classic issues with moving classes to another package that a developer should be aware of.